# Reduce the size of a proposition in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, error-handling

There is a function **simplify**, where `simplify :: Proposition -> Proposition`, where

```
data Proposition =  Const Bool 
                   | Var String
                   | And Proposition Proposition
                   | Or Proposition Proposition
                   | Not Proposition
                   deriving Show
```

It is used to reduce the size of a given proposition.

For example,

```
simplify (Const False `And` a) == Const False 
simplify (Const True `And` a)  == a
```

My attempt is to use pattern matching in that case:

```
simplify (Const False `And` a) = Const False
simplify (Const False `Or` a) = Const False
simplify (Const False `Not` a) = Const False
simplify (Const True `And` a) = a
simplify (Const True `Or` a) = a
simplify (Const True `Not` a) = a
simplify prop = prop
```

But I am receiving two types of errors:

1. The constructor ‘Not’ should have 1 argument, but has been given 2
2. Variable not in scope: a :: Proposition

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What would ``simplify (Const True `Not` a) = a`` do?

Comment: Futhermore ``simplify (Const True `Or` a) = a`` should be ``simplify (Const True `Or` a) = const True``

Comment: I would say returns a?

Comment: but `Not` takes only one parameter, hence ``const True `Not` a``, makes no sense, it should be `Not a`, or `Not (Const True)`, or something else. I strongly advice you to first try to *understand* what is happening, instead of trying to write more lines that look similar.

Comment: You mean `Not` cannot take both `Const True` and `a` ?

Comment: Oh,yeah. Right, it's declared as one argument Proposition.

Comment: So in `Not` case it will be `simplify ( Not (Const True)) = Const False` ?

Comment: exactly. Note that you furthermore first might want to simplify `a` itself, so recurse on `a` for certain simplifications.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that can be improved in your approach.

First, there are a few errors in your function, 
as already pointed out in the commments, the 'Not' constructor only takes one argument so

```
simplify (Const False `Not` a) = Const False
```

and

```
simplify (Const True `Not` a) = a
```

will not work.
In addition there are some logic errors,

```
simplify (Const False `Or` a) = Const False
```

and

```
simplify (Const True `Or` a) = a
```

are incorrect.

Once these are fixed, your function should properly simplify, but only on the top level of the proposition. In order to simplify the whole proposition you need to add recursive calls to each right side that includes a variable and add the missing cases that are currently covered by

```
simplify prop = prop
```

e.g. you should change your cases like

```
simplify (Const True `And` a) = a
```

to

```
simplify (Const True `And` a) = simplify a
```

and add cases like

```
simplify (a `And` b) = ((simplify a) `And` (Simplify b))
```

This way the function will go through the entire proposition and stop at the first level. One way to make sure you have all cases covered is to remove

```
simplify prop = prop
```

and make a case for each constructor.
For the variables, you can just write

```
simplify (Var a) = (Var a)
```

and that will leave them as they are.

In addition, top level functions are expected to have type annotations, so consider adding

```
simplify :: Proposition -> Proposition
```

above your function declaration.

A minor nitpick:
In cases like

```
simplify (Const False `And` a) = Const False
```

you don't need to bind a and can instead use a wildcard, like so:

```
simplify (Const False `And` _) = Const False
```

Comment: You made the same mistake! `simplify (Const True \`And\` a) = a` is correct. `simplify (Const True \`Or\` a) = a` is incorrect.